# VS2017 DOM Explorer turn off

Tags: debugging, dom, visual-studio-2017, explorer

I'm starting using VS2017 and noticed that for every HTML based project there's a DOM Explorer window appearing at launch. Problem: I don't want it, but I don't see how to turn off this option. I've already uncheked Tools->Options->Deguggin->General->"Enable JavaScript debugging for ASP.NET (Chrome and IE)" as a try, but the DOM Explorer window is still here.

Any idea how to turn it off ? Thanks for your help !

Comment: Would you please share me the detailed VS 2017 version information? I test it with my VS2017 Enterprise 15.3.3 version in window 10, if I disable "Enable JavaScript debugging for ASP.NET (Chrome and IE)", it would not show the DOM Explorer window. I just reset the VS with default settings, and then disable that option, if possible, you could test it as my steps. Or run your VS as the admin, view the result. I will also update VS2017 to latest version 15.3.4 and test it again later.

Comment: Thanks for your help. My VS 2017 version is 15.3.4. I installed the latest update and try again. I disabled the option, restarted VS, and run my cordova project on a genymotion emulator as device in Debug mode. DOM Explorer window is still here... Any chance to get rid of that window but keep the breaking points ?

Comment: I test it using the latest 15.3.4 in my window 10, if I disable "Enable JavaScript debugging for ASP.NET (Chrome and IE)", it would not show the DOM Explorer window in my side. Could you reset your VS settings? TOOLS->Import and Export Settings Wizard->Reset all settings->select “No, just reset settings, overwriting my current settings”->Choose a Default Collection of settings. I often use the C# settings, and then disable that option, debug it again. After you debug it, please also visit the option under Debug->Windows->DOM Explorer, whether "Show All" was disabled/gray?

Comment: If still no help, I suggest you disable any add-ins in your VS, or re-install/repair your VS, create a simple web project, test the result.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Resetting settings was the answer. Not bugged with the DOM Explorer window anymore. Thanks from me and my CPU ! ;-)

Comment: Glad to know that it has been resolved, I just add it as the answer, if possible, you could mark it. Have a nice day:)

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to disable the DOM Explorer when you launch the debugger - don't reset any settings or anything else...

All you need to do is **close the DOM Explorer window when debug session is on**, THEN stop debugging and **restart Visual Studio** for the change to be committed.

Once VS restarts you should not see Visual Studio open DOM Explorer for that project going forward. If you want to enable DOM Explorer again, you can do so by going to "Debug > Windows > DOM Explorer > Show All"

Comment: I tried this with VS2019 but the DOM Explorer still shows when debugging.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

TOOLS->Import and Export Settings Wizard->Reset all settings->select “No, just reset settings, overwriting my current settings”->Choose a Default Collection of settings. I often use the C# settings, and then disable option "Enable JavaScript debugging for ASP.NET (Chrome and IE)", debug it again.